# Wanting to import service accounts from a spreadsheet and set to password never expire

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, import-csv

```
Import-CSV "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\azureadusers.csv" | ForEach {
    Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $user.UserPrincipalName -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
}
```

The error I get is: Set-AzureADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null

Comment: Does the `azureadusers.csv` file have a `UserPrincipalName` column header?

Comment: quite simple, you csv does not contain the attribute userprincipalname or mabye some empty values

Comment: You’re on a foreach-object. Use $_ ínstead of $user which is not defined

Comment: jepp brice is right

Comment: It did work: Import-CSV "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\azureadusers.csv" | ForEach {
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.SamAccountName -PasswordPolicies DisablePasswordExpiration
}

Comment: Glad that you have fixed your issue. kindly post your fix as an answer so that it will helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem.